# IPv6: Server can't ping gateway (pfSense) but gets IP

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ipv6, pfsense

I have three servers which should now also get IPv6 connectivity besides the IPv4.
Servers:

1. Pi4 (Raspberry Pi OS)
2. Nextcloud (Debian 10; Nextcloud as snap)
3. Mailserver (Debian 10; mailcow as docker, which also uses IPv6)

They are directly connected to the firewall (up to date pfSense) and reside in their own subnet/VLAN. My plan is to use DCHPv6 so that I can give them a fixed IP, from where I can use DNS and firewall rules.
From my ISP I got /56 subnet via prefix daligation and in my network every subnet gets a /64 chunk of that.
The config of the DHCP-server is for all servers the same and is as follows:
RA-Advertisment -> managed
Range -> from ::d:000 to ::d:ffff

**Server 1. - Pi4**:
Gets the wanted v6 IP from the firewall (static entry) -> xxxxxxx::d:1. Can ping the firewall and the firewall can ping the host.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:ba:a6:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.2/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 5564sec preferred_lft 4664sec
    inet6 2a02:8106:26:c207::d:1/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6268sec preferred_lft 3568sec
    inet6 2a02:8106:26:c207:4f5b:7339:9f6f:6b9e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86394sec preferred_lft 14394sec
    inet6 fe80::3958:1364:8c6e:21ca/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.7.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.7.2 metric 202 
192.168.7.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.7.2 metric 202
```

```
$ cat nano /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

**Server 2. - Nextcloud**:
Gets not the wanted v6 IP from the firewall (static entry) -> xxxxxxx::d:1. I don't know why, but it gets one out of the DHCP range -> ::d:3066 without the static entry. Can ping the firewall and the firewall can ping the host. The server is reachable as wanted.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:76:7d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.2/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 6796sec preferred_lft 6796sec
    inet6 2a02:8106:26:c205::d:3066/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:fe76:7d6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:44:56:66:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:44ff:fe56:665e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: veth16f1c55@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 76:f8:c2:66:64:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::74f8:c2ff:fe66:64c2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth624ab49@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether f2:88:68:74:9b:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::f088:68ff:fe74:9ba7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.5.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.5.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.5.2
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
```

**Server 3. - Mailcow**:
Gets not the wanted v6 IP from the firewall (static entry) -> xxxxxxx::d:1. I don't know why, but it gets one out of the DHCP range -> 2a02:8106:26:c206::d:1fd7 without the static entry. Can't ping the firewall

```
$ ping 2a02:8106:26:c206:ec4:7aff:feac:791a 
connect: network is not reachable
```

and the firewall can't ping the host. The server is not reachable at all.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:ab:9c:b3:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.6.2/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 6115sec preferred_lft 6115sec
    inet6 2a02:8106:26:c206::d:1fd7/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20b:abff:fe9c:b340/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens36: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:ab:9c:b3:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:86:52:78:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:86ff:fe52:7826/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-mailcow: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:98:71:e4:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.1.1/24 brd 172.22.1.255 scope global br-mailcow
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:98ff:fe71:e400/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth9d1c8e9@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 92:69:ae:5f:16:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::9069:aeff:fe5f:1694/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: veth8c82697@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether ea:dd:2f:06:a8:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::e8dd:2fff:fe06:a8ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: vethe900989@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:45:28:e8:f8:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::ec45:28ff:fee8:f865/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: vethfca3d8a@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:0e:57:52:f6:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::700e:57ff:fe52:f68c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: veth047f50f@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 32:d4:40:15:0c:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::30d4:40ff:fe15:c7f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vethf6245fe@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 26:53:8b:26:c9:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::2453:8bff:fe26:c938/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: veth21a6fa3@if18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 5a:a7:a7:e2:86:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::58a7:a7ff:fee2:865b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: vethd2d1e06@if20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 8e:79:e5:0e:a6:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 10
    inet6 fe80::8c79:e5ff:fe0e:a6f1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: vethc10d2bc@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 76:99:da:1d:cd:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 9
    inet6 fe80::7499:daff:fe1d:cd0e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: veth201bcfc@if24: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 46:d4:93:82:4b:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 8
    inet6 fe80::44d4:93ff:fe82:4b6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: vethad8e436@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether da:24:e6:37:3a:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::d824:e6ff:fe37:3a8c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
29: vethbaf78e4@if28: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 9e:01:7b:70:9a:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 15
    inet6 fe80::9c01:7bff:fe70:9a31/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
31: veth7eada94@if30: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 2a:bd:24:d6:e9:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 13
    inet6 fe80::28bd:24ff:fed6:e98a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
33: vethd1e707c@if32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 7a:71:37:59:58:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 16
    inet6 fe80::7871:37ff:fe59:5843/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
35: veth6d78c43@if34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 42:f1:b5:53:f5:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 14
    inet6 fe80::40f1:b5ff:fe53:f55c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
37: vethd1a9600@if36: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 52:15:e7:eb:3e:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 11
    inet6 fe80::5015:e7ff:feeb:3eea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
39: veth621f244@if38: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 1e:af:a7:76:8e:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 12
    inet6 fe80::1caf:a7ff:fe76:8ec8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
41: veth4284cea@if40: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-mailcow state UP group default 
    link/ether 32:ee:4d:9c:fb:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 17
    inet6 fe80::30ee:4dff:fe9c:fb6c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.6.1 dev enp0s25 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.22.1.0/24 dev br-mailcow proto kernel scope link src 172.22.1.1 
192.168.6.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.6.2
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface enp0s25 inet6 dhcp
```

Why is server 3 not reachable, as it has the same configurations as server 2? Shouldn't an IPv6 address also be available in the routes?

best regards

Comment: Are all three of these on the same subnet / vlan? your wording is slightly unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that. They have their own subnet / vlan.